# hive-jdbc-standalone.jar not loaded by tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, jdbc, hive, tomcat7

I am trying to connect to hive thrift server (hiveserver2) from web application.
I created dynamic web project in Eclipse, and added following jars under WEB-INF/lib -

- hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar
- hive-jdbc-0.14.0.jar
- hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
- mongo-hadoop-core.jar
- mongo-hadoop-hive.jar
- mongo-java-driver.jar

I am using tomcat 7.0.61. When I deploy the application to tomcat server, it gives following message and does not load hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar

```
INFO:     validateJarFile(C:\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HiveWeb\WEB-INF\lib\hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

It seems javax.servlet.Servlet.class in hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar and tomcat/lib are conflicting. I need hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar for connecting to hiveserver.

I tried to add hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar in tomcat/lib directory. But tomcat fail to start due to that.

Is there a way to exclude javax.servlet.Servlet from either hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar or tomcat?

Comment: My guess would be that you **should not** include `hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar`; you aren't running standalone.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for the reply. But I need hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar for connecting to hive thrift server using jdbc. If I don't include that jar, java can not connect to hive server.

Comment: I'd guess that `hive-jdbc-0.14.0.jar` should be sufficient

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried that, but if I include only `hive-jdbc-0.14.0.jar`, I get     `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface`

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem @kshpra?

Answer (score 0):

You should try 
removing **hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar** and use below jars :

**hive-common--0.14.0.jar 
hive-exec-0.14.0.jar 
hive-metastore-0.14.0.jar 
hive-serde-0.14.0.jar 
hive-service-0.14.0.jar**

Answer (score 0):

You guess right.

Tomecat/lib/servlet-api.jar includes `javax.servlet` conflicts with `javax.servlet` in *hive-jdbc-x.x.x-standlone.jar*.

I think it's not recommended to use **hive-jdbc-x.x.x-standlone.jar** when your app deployed to the production environment, cause **hive-jdbc-x.x.x-standlone.jar** includes many other resources, it's quite easy to conflict with other *.jar.

So just remove **hive-jdbc-x.x.x-standlone.jar**, and add the following jar to classpath(HAVE BEEN TESTED).

1. hadoop-auth-x.x.x.jar
2. hadoop-common-x.x.x.jar
3. hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-x.x.x.jar
4. hive-exec-x.x.x.jar
5. hive-jdbc-x.x.x.jar
6. hive-metastore-x.x.x.jar
7. hive-service-x.x.x.jar